# Is it possible to enable persistance for some part of the Redis data?

Tags: caching, redis, persistence

I want to use Redis RDB persistence, but I need persistency for only small part of the data. How can I configure Redis to take snapshot for some part of data. Is it possible or I need 2 different Redis DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it. You'll need 2 different Redis *instances*.